# Как установить минимальные размеры медиафайлов для заданной рубрики?

Tags: php, wordpress, фильтры, хук

На сайте `wordpress` *только для рубрики новости* необходимо сделать ограничение на загрузку минимальных размеров изображений в админке.

Делаю по примеру [статьи](https://www.wphook.ru/media/minimum-media-sizes.html) (для всех рубрик работает), но вот вычленить для конкретной рубрики мне не удается, т.к. проверка 
`if(in_category('news',$post->ID)) {}` похоже отрабатывает после фильтра.

**Код**

```
//ограничение на загрузку медиафайлов по размеру start
function wph_minimum_media_sizes($file) {
    global $post;
    if(in_category('news',$post->ID)) {
        $mimes = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');

        if(!in_array($file['type'], $mimes))
            return $file;

        $img = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
        //установка значений минимальных размеров
        $minimum = array('width' => 684, 'height' => 456);

        if ($img[0] < $minimum['width'])
            $file['error'] = 
                'Изображение слишком маленькое. Минимальная ширина ' 
                . $minimum['width'] 
                . 'px. Ширина загружаемого изображения ' 
                . $img[0] . 'px.';

        elseif ($img[1] < $minimum['height'])
            $file['error'] = 
                'Изображение слишком маленькое. Минимальная высота ' 
                . $minimum['height'] 
                . 'px. Высота загружаемого изображения ' 
            . $img[1] . 'px.';
    }

    return $file;
}
//если пользователь не администратор, то включаем фильтр на минимальный размер
function wph_upload_prefilter() {
    add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wph_minimum_media_sizes');
} 
add_action('admin_init', 'wph_upload_prefilter');
//ограничение на загрузку медиафайлов по размеру end
```

Comment: Хотелка не правильная. Надо не ограничивать загрузку, а **выводить** нужные размеры в нужных местах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глобальная переменная `$post` определена только во время главного цикла WordPress. Во время работы фильтра она равна `null`. То же самое можно сказать и о функции `in_category()` - она имеет смысл только во время главного цикла WordPress.

Так что этот код работать не будет. Да и сама идея непонятна. Во время загрузки изображения в библиотеку медиа, как даже человеку распознать, где будет использовано данное изображение?

Comment: имеется ввиду во время публикации статьи, когда человек подгружает изображение, если выбрана определенная рубрика, то он не может загрузить меньше допустимого размера

Comment: А если он не выбрал рубрику? Если он сначала грузит изображение, а потом добавляет рубрику? А если он потом захочет перевести опубликованную статью из одной рубрики в другую? Тут сплошные дыры в логике, к сожалению.

Comment: Лучше, наверное, задать минимальный размер для любых изображений, создать кастомные размеры изображений, и при выводе из других рубрик использовать другой, меньший размер.